# How can I get rid of the columns header when the style 'Boxed' was selected?

Tags: 2013, jquery, css

I created a new list view with style = 'Boxed' in SP2013.
The problem is that this view is showing the columns header in the top when there's no need to do it.
So, how can I remove or hide it?
I tried associating a js file where I'm loading jQuery and doing the following:

```
$('.ms-listviewtable tr th').hide();
```

But if after loading jQuery, the Boxed style doesn't work anymore.
Any ideas?

Comment: i checked and it's working fine..  i think your javascript loads before. try to apply delay to your javascript and check...

Comment: It didn't work for me. I'm executing the command after loading jQuery, but when the jQuery script has been loaded the boxed style doesn't work anymore, strange isn't it?

Comment: yes, you can also hide by applying css...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Probably the most simple way to hide View header would be to use CSS

1 Add Content Editor web part on View page (located under Media & Content category)

2 Insert the following code into `Content`

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ms-viewheadertr { display:none; }
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! :D

Comment: Glad to know :)

Comment: That worked perfectly for my SP2013 list in boxed view! I don't get why Microsoft took the split view/edit capability out of SP Designer 2013... - Thanks!!!

Comment: Works like a charm until I publish the page, <style type="text/css"> .ms-viewheadertr { display:none; }
</style> After publishing it looks like.... <style type="text/css"> <span id="ms-rterangecursor-start"> </span> <span id="ms-rterangecursor-end"></span> tr.ms-{;} </style><span id="ms-rterangecursor-start"></span> <span id="ms-rterangecursor-end"></span>

Comment: Wonderful!  Be sure to use a good Title for the Content Editor web part that houses your CSS in the HTML source - or months later when you return to this webpart, and see no content in the CE, you'll wonder why it's there and perhaps delete it.  Set the title to something like: `Edit HTML Source CSS to Hide Column Headers` and then set the `Chrome Type` to none in the Web Part's `Appearance` settings.  The title will show when you are in web-part edit mode, but not in display mode, so nobody else will see it but you.

Answer (score 3):

To hide specific WebPart's column headers

```
#WebPartWPQ6 .ms-viewheadertr
  {
   display: none;
   }
```

.... where replace `WebPartWPQn` with your web part ID.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue that once I publish the page the feature stops working.

I solved it by adding a **Script Editor Web Part** and **adding the code Vadim posted** there.

[image]