# Webpart ID to hide column headers for specific list webpart view

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, list-view, id

How do I find the webpart ID so I can hide the column headers for a specific list webpart view?  I want to use the following code in content editor...

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ms-viewheadertr { display:none; }
</style>
```

This thread relates to the same question but doesn't tell how to find the webpart ID.
[How can I get rid of the columns header when the style 'Boxed' was selected?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85735/how-can-i-get-rid-of-the-columns-header-when-the-style-boxed-was-selected/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the WebPart ID using `Developer Tools (F12)` in Internet Explorer as the following:

- Open your page that contains your list view via Internet Explorer > edit it.
- Click F12 to open developer tools, Click on the Pointer icon, and catch the div with class `s4-wpcell ms-webpartzone-cell ms-webpart-cell-vertical ms-fullWidth` and get its ID as the following:

[image]

---

**To hide the column headers,**

Add the below script based on your webpart ID in `Script Editor` or `Content Editor web part`.

```
<style>
#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2 .ms-viewheadertr
  {
   display: none;
   }
</style>
```

**[Output]**

No columns headers as highlighted with yellow

[image]

Comment: This worked perfect.  The visual was very helpful.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JarrettJones Glad to hear it worked and helped you, please don't forget to **Mark** my answer :) it's the true sign beside my answer.