# Bring list Column headers back

Tags: list, column, style.css

Following a great tip from [How can I get rid of the columns header when the style 'Boxed' was selected?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85735/how-can-i-get-rid-of-the-columns-header-when-the-style-boxed-was-selected)

I was able to hide all the column headers and everyone was happy! Until of course someone (that pays the bills) asked that for that one list, I bring back the headers.
I added a bit of code in the webpart to reverse the effect. I used

```
.ms-viewheadertr
 { display: none;}
```

replacing none by: block, inherit, contents, grid... everything I could think of. Some work but the headers are not aligned with the columns, they appear in the wrong place. I would appreciate some advice on this. Thanks

Comment: You could try `.ms-viewheadertr { display: inherit !important;}`. This should override any CSS that doesn't also have the `!implortant` instruction.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, that did not work. The columns are not on top of the data. 
It shows all the headers with nothing under them, then to the right of that all the data

Comment: Could you add a screen shot showing whats going wrong?

Comment: Hi, I added screenshots at https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1olMqijGPUrabummi7JtUzhidbpEF--CB?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
.ms-viewheadertr
 { display: "";}
```

It has worked for me every time.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that made no difference.

Comment: check your class "ms-viewheadertr". Is this applied to the header rows?

Comment: Hi, I added screenshots https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1olMqijGPUrabummi7JtUzhidbpEF--CB?usp=sharing